# Jquery link handler not working with Google Ads Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to integrate Jquery with a Google Ads Link, and it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the Jquery:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('div.class a').click(function() {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

This is the Google Ads Link:

```
<a id="aw0" class="adt" target="_top" onmouseover="return ss('','aw0')" onmousedown="st('aw0')" onfocus="ss('','aw0')" onclick="ha('aw0')" href="/aclk?sa=l&ai=BH3xd2ZmTSvrMC5iKqAO2v7XDBv6jtl-mgLjKDMCNtwGA8QQQARgBILCNuQooBTgAUO3uw-4EYPEDoAHdtsH_A7IBCWxvY2FdsG9zdLoBCjE2MHg2MDBfYXPIAQHaARdodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0L21lZHV1L8gCrOj9A6gDAcgDB-gDigPoA9gC6AMf6AMg9QMAAAAE&num=1&sig=AGiWqtyWbhq4GCyGudApdZUjBApw4vI74w&client=ca-pub-0099118250769400&adurl=http://www.nixusoftware.com/products_nss.html">
  <span>Nixu Software's Warning</span>
</a>
```

Other links seem to work fine, but not the Google Ads Link.

Why won't the Google Ads Link fire my `onclick` handler in Jquery?

Comment: How do you mean not properly work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell ads are displayed in an iframe. You don't have access to iframe content for security reasons.

Comment: how to handle ads link.Is there any way